# php session or cookies for checkboxes and jquery remove

Tags: php, jquery, session, checkbox

The user selects which properties they'd like to keep by checking the checkbox. When they click "view chosen" I would like the page to reload and show their selection. The below code works but when I add a page refresh it forgets the selection. I think I need to use php sessions or cookies to store the chosen data. Which is better? Is it a simple or quite complicated?

```
 <ul>
 <li class="property-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="category1"></input>
    <div>content</div>
 </li>
 <li class="property-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="category1"></input>
    <div>content</div>
 </li>
 <li class="property-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="category1"></input>
    <div>content</div>
 </li>
 </ul>
 <button id="button">View Chosen</button>
<script>
jQuery( "#button" ).click(function() {
    jQuery(".property-list").find("#myCheck").each(function(){
if (jQuery(this).prop('checked') == false){ 
      jQuery(this).parent( ".property-list" ).remove();
}
});
});
</script>
```

This code works fine but doesn't refresh the page. It must have a page reload as it will be turned into a PDF.

Comment: Take a gander: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: I would recommend you to use jQuery cookies. Just include jQuery cookies library and use it.